# Custom option file field on product page takes too much time to upload file - magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have created a custom field for file upload for a product.The uploading works well with small file size but when i upload large files its taking too much time to upload , any ideas on how to speed up the process ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

replace your 56k modem with a decent internet connection :) sorry i dont think this will be related to the upload feature.

Comment: Then provide answer that is related to the upload feature ;)

Comment: its just a file upload. i am sure its only a slow connection problem.